# How are people patching multiple jboss stacks (RPM install) on a single server?

Tags: jboss, rpm, yum, rhel, jboss-eap-6

We install jboss-eap6 via RHEL rpm (RH 6) and configure jbossas for four separate stacks.  After trying to configure with links as we do for apache and php, we gave up and made copies of the software via puppet.  That was advised here on stackoverflow and several other sources.  In fact, the startup file that comes with RH does the copy (we configure an xml file beforehand).

The problem is, when we run yum update the RPM is updated but the copies aren't.  There are a couple of ways I can think to get around the problem but I've searched and haven't found a "best practice".  Anyone have a clever way to handle this situation?

Thanks,

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but why have separate installs? Domain mode makes it easy to manage multiple servers from a single location. Plus RPM updates would work.

Comment: Domain was new for us, and the customer was under the gun because one of the stack components was out of support.  He didn't feel comfortable taking that step on top of all new versions for O/S and all the other components of the stack.  This issue may be a wedge to move in that direction, but as I recall he also had some other issues with the way domain did things.  I don't remember the details though.

Comment: Ah got it. It might be worth contacting support then. I'm not sure what the best solution would be.